# Book Digitization: Is Google Document AI Necessary?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I have a question about Google Document AI:
I intend to create a digitization service dedicated to Libraries.
My goal is to digitize old books (no manuscripts). The result must be a PDF with the scanned image of the book and OCR functions as well as obviously the possibility of carrying out text searches. These PDFs must also be viewed on online platforms via the various viewers most used by libraries.

My question is this: is "Google Document AI" essential for this type of project or is any software with text recognition functions sufficient?

I expect someone more experienced than me to help me. thanks